# Teimani/Yemenite Siddur in English

Tags: prayer-book, english, yemenite-temani

I am converting to Judaism and wish to adopt Teimani minhagim. Unfortunately, I cannot fully read Hebrew so I am looking for a Yemenite (Teimani) Siddur in English. Please send me PDF or a link to where I can purchase one.

Comment: If no one has a link here, then if you're among a Teimani community (which I hope you are if you're taking on such customs), then someone there (the Rabbi?) should be able to help! Good luck on your journey!

Comment: No such siddur currently exists. The closest thing to it would be a translation of the Rambam's Seder ha-Tefillah at the back of Sefer Ahavah. Also, it is worth noting that there is not a monolithic Temani nusah, the two main divisions are Baladi and Shami. Of additional note is that Temanim traditionally refer to their siddur as a tiklal.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ya'akov and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: please note that many authorities say a convert should adopt the minhagim of the place he is converting at, not pick and choose however he wishes so unless you are converting with a teimani community and beis din i don't think it's a wise idea what you're doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spoke to an American I know who converted to Judaism and moved to Israel and adopted Yemenite customs. He confirmed that there is currently no such siddur on the market.

He says what he did was to use a transliterated Ashkenazi siddur and "pray in English what he had to pray in English and not worry about it" until he was able to master enough Hebrew for the daily prayers.

He also recommended deciding whether you want to adopt Shami (Yemenite with some Sephardic/Arizal influences) or Baladi (without the Sephardic influences) customs, as "there is a difference".

Comment: I am very happy that there are other converts that have adopted Temani/Yemenite customs. Hopefully one day someone will translate the Baladi Teimani Siddur, there are a lot of coverts that want to adopt Teimani customs.

Comment: I know many converts who have done so (here in Israel). It seems the same reasoning that draws them to Judaism draws them to this nusach. I get it. Rabbi David Bar-Hayim breaks down the reasoning quite persuasively  Much luck with the conversion process- as you've seen it's more than a tad controversial in some circles to do what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 2):

As others before me have said, there currently is no such siddur. I am actually in the process of having such a siddur made with the pirush (commentary) of Maharitz (one of the greatest yemenite rabbis who wrote the most extensive commentary on the tiklal). It does take a lot of funding, so if this is something you're interested in supporting please let me know. (we have a tax deductible organization)